# Why output is different in "()=>{}" and "function () {}" function

Tags: javascript

I thought the output would be same in ()=>{}  and function(){} but I got a different output.

1. With function(){}

   ```
   var person = {};
   person.name = 'egoing';
   person.introduce = function(){
   return 'My name is '+this.name;
   }
   document.write(person.introduce());
   ```

the output was

```
'My name is egoing'
```

2. But with ()=>{} function,

   ```
   var person = {};
   person.name = 'egoing';
   person.introduce = person.introduce=()=>{
   return 'My name is ' +this.name}
   document.write(person.introduce());
   ```

output was

```
'My name is '
```

Why is it differnt??

Comment: Arrow functions do not have`this` set to reference anything.

Comment: Thank you marekful

Comment: Interestingly you'd have got `My name is undefined` if you'd chosen almost anything other than `name` as the property - you're actually hitting `window.name` here

Comment: @JamesThorpe Wow! That's interesting!!

Comment: @marekful What can I do to reference `this` of arrow function? Should i just not use it when I want to use `this`?

Comment: That is right..